# Alamofire Manager with Swift 2.0 getting Cancelled

Tags: swift2, alamofire

I have a Swift 2.0 ApiManager class using Alamofire 2.0 with the following init:

```
var manager:Manager

init() {
    var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
    defaultHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(UserAccount.sharedInstance.token)"

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

    manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
}
```

Example function:

```
func getMe(completion:(jsonObject: NSDictionary) -> ()) {
    manager.request(.GET, Constants.apiURL + "me").responseJSON { request, response, result in

        print(self.manager) //THIS LINE FIXES IT

        switch result {
        case .Success(let json):
            completion(jsonObject: json as! NSDictionary)
        case .Failure(let data, let error):
            print("Error: \(__FUNCTION__)\n", data, error)
        }
    }
}
```

The error I receive:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
```

It appears the request gets cancelled because the manager is being deallocated. Adding the print statement prevents the manager from being deallocated and it works perfect then. But I'm trying to find a better solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was running to this same issue, I used this to fix it

```
class Session {
    static let sharedInstance = Session()

     private var manager : Manager?

        func ApiManager()->Manager{
            if let m = self.manager{
                return m
            }else{
                let defaultHeaders = ["X-Version":"Some header"]

                let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
                configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

                let tempmanager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
                self.manager = tempmanager
                return self.manager!
            }
        }
    }
```

then I called it with

```
    Session.sharedInstance.ApiManager().request(...
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issue. I just added the line `static let sharedInstance = ApiManager()` to my class then called it just like you said. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Groarus, you did use `static let sharedInstance = ApiManager()` or `static let sharedInstance = ApiManager`?. The first throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Its resolved here in their github issues
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/157

Comment: Unfortunately that solution doesn't work with Swift 2 and Alamofire 2.